# Linksys SFE2000 Interface

Tags: routing, switch, linksys

I have a real problem with a layer 3 Linksys switch.

First, every time it looses power, it seems to reset back to an older config. Not only this, but when this happens it looses interface settings on one subnet.

This would not be a problem but I am completely unable to get to the interface on the working side. It allows me to log on and then just displays a blank screen. I have tried this on:

IE6
IE7
IE8
IE9
Firefox 3.5
Opera
Chrome

All with the same results, except for Opera, which loads half the interface but nothing I can really use. I really need to get onto this switch so I can sort out routing and VLAN tagged ports, so if anyone has any ideas on either of these issues please let me know ASAP!

Thanks!

Also, due to its location and my lack of laptops with serial connections I cannot putty into it.

UPDATE:

Looked into this a bit more and it looks like this model of switch does not save the current config to boot unless you make sure to save it yourself, which explains the first issue, however the broken interface is more worrying!

Comment: Instead of accessing the switch from a browser, access it using `ssh`.

Comment: Pretty much every switch is like that. Otherwise, if you made a configuration change that locked you out, how would you get back in?

Comment: Yea sure, my mistake. Also, managed to get into it via Telnet and then enabled SSH connections, which has given me enough access to fix the routing issues.

Comment: Also, if anyone else has this issue, it seems that the HTTPS interface is working. David, do you want to rewrite your comments as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of accessing the switch from a browser, access it using `ssh`. Getting access to work from a browser is much more complicated than just getting into the switch. From the console, you should pretty easily be able to fix the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

No serial port on a laptop is solvable by a $ 20 serial 2 USB converter cable.

Everyone who deals with switches should have one ready together with the console cable.

If TCP/IP access to the switch is unstable (which your problem description seems to imply) getting on the switch using telnet or ssh is probably unstable too.

I would give it a try anyway, but make sure not to do any save of the settings until you have a complete config.

That way, if you get locked out by network issues or your own actions you can ask someone on-site to power-cycle the switch and you will be back to your current starting point.